# Reading files and directories within compressed war archive

Tags: java, io, executable-jar

I'm trying to access a folder inside a compressed war archive but with no success.

Archive structure:

```
app.war                
       |- META-INF       
       |- org               
       |- WEB-INF             
                   |- classes 
                              |- com       
                              |- static    
                              |- testcases      
                                          |- 1          
                                          |- 2...       
                                          |- ...22      
                                                   |- README.txt (file)
                                                   |- TEST.CASE  (file)
```

This is my code for reading the contents of the directory **testcases**:

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("testcases");

LOG.debug("PROTOCOL=" + url.getProtocol());   

List<String> files = IOUtils.readLines(url.openStream());

LOG.debug("DIRS=" + files.size());
LOG.debug("PATH=" + url.getPath());
for (String s : files)
    LOG.debug(s);
```

Running in eclipse the output I get is:

```
TestCaseUtil : PROTOCOL=file
TestCaseUtil : DIRS=22
TestCaseUtil : PATH=/C:/Users/{Name}/development/git/app/target/classes/testcases    
TestCaseUtil : 1    
...             
TestCaseUtil : 22
```

When I execute the war from command line with `java -jar app.war` I get the following output:

```
TestCaseUtil : PROTOCOL=jar
TestCaseUtil : DIRS=0
TestCaseUtil : PATH=file:/C:/Users/{Name}/development/git/app/target/app.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/testcases
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working snippet (all credit goes to user [Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen) for providing the code base):

```
Map<String, ?> env = new HashMap<>();
URL url = getClass().getResource("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
LOG.debug("MANIFEST=" + url.toURI());

// Correct the URL to either file system or war
{
    String s = url.toString().replaceFirst("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF", ""); // In case of war
    url = new URL(s); // Use jar:file: ...
    LOG.debug("ARCHIVE=" + url.toURI());
}

FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(url.toURI(), env);
LOG.debug("FILESYSTEM=" + fs.isOpen());

Path path = fs.getPath("/WEB-INF/classes/testcases");
LOG.debug("PATH=" + path.getFileName());

Set<FileVisitOption> options = new HashSet<FileVisitOption>();

int maxDepth = 1;

FileVisitor<Path> visitor = new FileVisitor<Path>() {

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        LOG.debug(file.getFileName());
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

};

Files.walkFileTree(path, options, maxDepth, visitor);
```

And the expected output:

```
TestCaseUtil      : MANIFEST=jar:file:/C:/Users/{Name}/development/git/app/target/app.war!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
TestCaseUtil      : ARCHIVE=jar:file:/C:/Users/{Name}/development/git/app/target/app.war!/
TestCaseUtil      : FILESYSTEM=true
TestCaseUtil      : PATH=testcases
TestCaseUtil      : 1/ 
...
TestCaseUtil      : 22/
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing anything wrong.

When you run the project in `eclipse` it will keep the compiled class files in `target` folder instead of the actual `war` file structure.

But when you create a `war` file, required class files will be moved under `WEB-INF/classes` folder.

Hence the different results. Just make sure that when you create a WAR file it has the required folders/classes inside it, and you can verify it using any ZIP utility.

Comment: I can see that much myself from the path but what do I need to do to read the content of app.war/.../testcases successfully?

Answer (score 1):

The **FileSystem** provides virtual file systems, for zip files, but also for class path resources.

```
Map<String,?> env = new HashMap<>();
URL url = getClass().getResource("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");

// Correct the URL to either file system or war
{
    String s = url.toString()
        .replaceFirst("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF", "")
        .replaceFirst("\\!.*$", ""); // In case of war
    url = new URL("jar:" + s); // Use jar:file: ...
}

FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(url.toURI(), env);

Path path = fs.getPath("/WEB-INF/classes/testcases");
Set<FileVisitOption> options = ...
int maxDepth = 1;
FileVisitor<? super Path> visitor = ...
Files.walkFileTree(path, options, maxDepth, visitor);
```

Comment: I'll try that right away. Give me 5 minutes! Edit: FileSystem.newFileSystem() expects a Path not a String. How do I get an instance of Path?

Comment: Sorry that I started wrong; (Friday evening at work.) The code still is not entirely correct for the file system (then no jar:)

Comment: No worries, I know this situation. I'm trying to implement your updated code right now. So far it looks really good. I'll provide a snippet when I'm done :)

Comment: Okay I finally got it. Thanks a lot for your help!